# Spring Security Context - Session-size grows large

Tags: spring, session, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring Security 3.2.4 in a Spring **Webflow** application. Problem is that **XRebel** is warning me because the session is growing rapidly and gets to big.

When I inspect the session using **XRebel** it shows that its the Security Context object from Spring that is causing this. This object is quickly around **40MB**.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

We are using authentication from **LDAP** and we want our authorization to be collected from our application database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 40Mb... For an object that contains not that much. you don't have a custom `UserDetails` implementation by any chance?

Comment: @M.Deinum: Yes we do.

Comment: Thank you @M.Deinum. Even though you didn´t say much, you pointed me to the solution :) Of course the ldap-result stored every little detail in our UserDetails object. So the solution should be to only use the GrantedAuthorities that we extract form the database-results on authorization-lookup, and not all that is listed in LDAP.

Comment: That will probably help. LDAP trees and the generated content around it can be huge... I would simlpy extract what you need.